# When does qt classes work as smart pointers

Tags: c++, qt

For example:

```
QFile* file = new QFile...
```

If there is no `delete file` is it memory leak? I ask because I'm new in Qt and reviewing some code I've found this so I wonder if that is sane for Qt classes or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using QFile, there are usually no reason to make it dynamic, but yes -> delete should be here, or else it will leak.

in Qt there are only one exception from mandatory rule "for each new there should be delete".

If you are creating widget with parent like this:

```
QWidget* w = new QWidget();
QWidget* w2 = new QWidget(w);
```

Once you you delete w - all it's children (w2 in our case) also will be deleted. This shortens code, but this is only an exception. Rest of stuff - should be deleted.

Edited: Of course, you can use QScopedPointer, or usual std::unique_ptr.

Comment: Stack is also your friend

Comment: See [Object trees & ownership](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html).

Answer (score 1):

The rule is simple. If `QObject` has a `parent` then it will be deleted by `parent`. If not, you should delete it yourself.